# Rudin vs Lax's Functional Analysis book

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am reading Lax's functional analysis book and find the way it is written fits my current level just right, i.e., I might not be able to follow a more difficult book, even if that book is just slightly more difficult than Lax's. However, I am taking it formally next year and the textbook used for the course is Rudin's functional analysis.

**My question is:** How is Rudin's book compared to Lax's? Is it for more advanced students or is it just right for me?

Comment: Rudin is known for concise but reasonably self-contained exposition.  That said, his Functional Analysis book is aimed at second year graduate students in mathematics.  Lax is also a skilled writer but aims at exposition for those with an interest in applied math (applications).  Rudin will challenge you through exercises to reason rigorously as he does (a good choice for graduate studies).

Comment: @hardmath So Rudin's book is more challenging?

Comment: I would have to guess about "difficulty".  It sounds like you will be using Rudin's Functional Analysis as a course textbook next year.  A review of Lax's Functional Analysis can be [read here](https://noncommutativeanalysis.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/a-few-words-on-the-book-functional-analysis-by-peter-lax/), and it may reinforce your impressions or my note that it emphasizes applications.  My advice is not to avoid a book's treatment because of its difficulty, because often a well-written book will repay your effort in mastering it.